# how to calculate the given factorial equation of huge numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, math

How can I find the last digit of `X^(N!)`?

`X` can go up to `10^9`

`N` can go up to `10^18`

I know how to do it when only one of them is large but not both.

ps: execution time is 1 sec

Comment: Do you mean `X^(N! mod 10)` ? Logically factorial for all numbers are even numbers except for 0 and 1.  So `N! mod 10 = 1` for N = 0 or N = 1 and `N! mod 10 = 0` for the rest.

Comment: no i meant (X^(N!))/mod10 i have edited@Anouar

Comment: What does `.../mod10` even mean?  `Mod10` isn't a value that you can divide into other values.

Comment: @pjs mod10 was just for last digit, i have edited

Comment: can you not simply calculate the value you're looking for, then return `val%10` (i.e. val(mod10))?

Comment: @classicdude7 It's fine to use `mod 10`, but doesn't mean anything after a division symbol.

Comment: @pjs it was a typo

Comment: How do you do them separately, and why do you think it would not work when combined?

Comment: @norok2 i can calulate factorial of large number but to evaluate (x^y) where both of them are large, it exceeds time n memory

Comment: I thought you had a way to compute `n! mod m`.

Comment: Just to be clear, eventually you are after `pow(x, math.factorial(y), 10)` except that for large values of `x` and `y` it is taking forever. Is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no proof for this but...

Let's assume our target function is:

```
import math


def pow_fact_mod_last_digit_exact(x, y):
    return pow(x, math.factorial(y), 10)
```

but for large values of `x` and `y` this would just take too long.

This is actually equivalent to:

```
import math


def pow_fact_mod_last_digit(x, y):
    return pow(x, math.factorial(min(y, 4)), 10)
```

To test it for the first few hundred numbers:

```
print(all(
    pow_fact_mod_last_digit(x, y) == pow_fact_mod_last_digit_exact(x, y)
    for x in range(-300, 300) for y in range(300)))
# True
```

---

## How did I went for it (empirically)

Let us just observe how `pow(x, y, 10)` behaves for some values of `x` and `y`:

```
n = 20  # x
m = 24  # y
print(f'{"":2s}', end=' ')
for y in range(m):
    print(f'{y:2d}', end=' ')
print()
for x in range(n):
    print(f'{x:2d}', end=' ')
    for y in range(m):
        print(f'{pow(x, y, 10):2d}', end=' ')
    print()
```

```
    0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 
 0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 
 2  1  2  4  8  6  2  4  8  6  2  4  8  6  2  4  8  6  2  4  8  6  2  4  8 
 3  1  3  9  7  1  3  9  7  1  3  9  7  1  3  9  7  1  3  9  7  1  3  9  7 
 4  1  4  6  4  6  4  6  4  6  4  6  4  6  4  6  4  6  4  6  4  6  4  6  4 
 5  1  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5 
 6  1  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6 
 7  1  7  9  3  1  7  9  3  1  7  9  3  1  7  9  3  1  7  9  3  1  7  9  3 
 8  1  8  4  2  6  8  4  2  6  8  4  2  6  8  4  2  6  8  4  2  6  8  4  2 
 9  1  9  1  9  1  9  1  9  1  9  1  9  1  9  1  9  1  9  1  9  1  9  1  9 
10  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
11  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 
12  1  2  4  8  6  2  4  8  6  2  4  8  6  2  4  8  6  2  4  8  6  2  4  8 
13  1  3  9  7  1  3  9  7  1  3  9  7  1  3  9  7  1  3  9  7  1  3  9  7 
14  1  4  6  4  6  4  6  4  6  4  6  4  6  4  6  4  6  4  6  4  6  4  6  4 
15  1  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5 
16  1  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6 
17  1  7  9  3  1  7  9  3  1  7  9  3  1  7  9  3  1  7  9  3  1  7  9  3 
18  1  8  4  2  6  8  4  2  6  8  4  2  6  8  4  2  6  8  4  2  6  8  4  2 
19  1  9  1  9  1  9  1  9  1  9  1  9  1  9  1  9  1  9  1  9  1  9  1  9
```

So, it looks like to get `pow(x, y, 10)` you only need you only need to know `x % 10` (of course) and `(y - 1) % 4`.

Now, the factorial of a number `factorial(n) % k` is `0` for `n > k` and we only need to take care, at most, for the case of `n <= k`.

For the case of `k = 4`, we have:

```
import math


print([(i, math.factorial(i) % 4) for i in range(10)])
# [(0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 2), (4, 0), (5, 0), (6, 0), (7, 0), (8, 0), (9, 0)]
```

So we do not need to worry for values of `y` above 4 as they will behave like 4.

---

**EDIT**: Apparently this is *obvious* from Fermat's Little Theorem (but it was not obvious to me O:-) ) and [@OneLyner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61872893/5218354) contain essentially the same observations as above, as well as the reference to the theorem in the comments.

Comment: 12/21 test cases passed still..i think there are some conditions  which is not taken care of.

Comment: @classicdude7 It looks like it works for negative `x` too, for negative `y` factorial is undefined. Could you provide some `x` and `y` for which the 2 are not the same?

Answer (score 3):

Use the fact that

```
pow(x, k, 10) = pow(x % 10, 1 + (k-1) % 4, 10)
```

You just need to know the factorial modulo 4.

And obviously, `N > 3 => N! % 4 == 0`, which should make your life easy.

Comment: what about memory and time constraints?

Comment: Extremely small! What do you think?

Comment: but this is partially correct only 8/26 test cases passed only

Comment: Any counter example?

Comment: @OneLyner Can you give a citation for that relationship?

Comment: 400,400    the output should be 1 , its coming zero

Comment: `400^big = (40*10)^big = (40^big)*(10^big)` it's a multiple of 10, the last digit is 0.

Comment: @pjs this is a direct application of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem applied mod 5 and mod 2 here

Comment: Nitpick: you need `k >= 1` for your relationship to hold, so you'd still need to special-case `k=0`. (But of course `N!` will never be `0`.)